# jQuery: Allow user to select only one link per UL

Tags: jquery

I am building a quiz that has several questions that have 3 possible choices the user can choose which are identified by a,b or c. They can only choose one answer per `<ul>` (question) and if they choose another option, then the previous option becomes deselected.

This is the HTML markup I have so far:

```
<div class="question">
                        <h3>1. If you have a choice how do you prefer to talk to people?</h3>
                        <ul class="abc Clearfix">
                            <li>
                                <a class="a" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">A</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">By Text or Email</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="b" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">B</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">Talk on the phone</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="c" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">C</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">In person</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="question">
                        <h3>2. If you wanted to cook a meal how would you do it?</h3>
                        <ul class="abc Clearfix">
                            <li>
                                <a class="a" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">A</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">Read through a recipe</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="b" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">B</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">Get someone to talk you through it</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="c" href="javascript:void(false);">
                                    <span class="letter">C</span>
                                    <span class="image"></span>
                                    <span class="title">In person</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
 $(".abc li a").click(function ()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
```

1.) How would I make it so that only one option per question can be selected

2.) If user changes mind how do I make the previous option deselected

Comment: Wouldn't radio buttons be better for this?

Comment: No as they are not inputs and require much more html than radios

Comment: Should the user be able to deselect their choice by clicking it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will deselect all options then select the option the user clicked. Meaning only one will be selected at a time. Will also deselect the selected item if you click it again.

```
$(".abc li a").click(function () {
    var t = $(this);
    var ul = t.closest('ul.abc');
    var selected = t.hasClass('selected');
    ul.find('li a').removeClass('selected');
    if (!selected)
        t.addClass('selected');
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/huW4k/1/

Comment: This works great. But what about allowing the user to deselect as well? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As *Richard D* pointed out, radio buttons would be the ideal solution. You can manipulate them as well with `jQuery`, if that's what keeps you from using them.

If you absolutely want to use the current html, you can use this `jQuery` code :

```
$(".abc a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent('ul').find('a').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And here's the same code which will unselect the item if it was already selected.

```
$(".abc a").click(function () {
    isSelected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
    $(this).parent('ul').find('a').removeClass('selected')
    if(!isSelected) $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I am able to select as many options as I want with this code. I want to restrict it to one option per question. :)

Comment: No, as `selected` class is removed from every `a` of the `ul`, only one `a` will be selected at a time.